# How to get the value from an input field into a const and log it

Tags: javascript, input, cypress

How to get the text input field value to a 'const' variable in Cypress, so that I can log that variable using cy.log(). The below code doesn't log anything, can someone familiar with Cypress.io please advise

```
cy.get('input[name="email"]').then(($text)=>{
        const txt = $text.text()
        cy.log(txt)

    })
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Using `invoke('val')` instead of `invoke('text')` worked for my case.

Reminder of the html tag

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
```

Cypress code

```js
cy.get('input[name="email"]')
  .invoke('val')
  .then(sometext => cy.log(sometext));
```

Comment: .invoke('val') is magic! i was trying for hours to get the v-text-field value. thanks!!

Answer (score 58):

> Cypress official solution [How do I get an input’s value?](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html#How-do-I-get-an-input%E2%80%99s-value) suggests something like this code below:

```js
cy.get('input[name="email"]').should('have.value', val)
```

Comment: Not quite what was asked, but useful for other cases

Comment: after using .type() this sometimes (only happens in CI) has a wrong value for some reason, most of the time only with 1 MISSING LETTER. any ideas?

Comment: @trainoasis try adjusting the typing speed

Answer (score 24):

From https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/630

You should be able to do:

```
cy
  .get('input[name="email"]')
  .invoke('val') 
  .then(text => {
    const someText = text;
    cy.log(someText);
  });
```

This is working for me in a test on the following element:

```
<span class="abProgress" style="width: 0%;">100%</span>
```

Comment: I have tried that, now it's throwing an error 'cypress_runner.js:141304 TypeError: $el.invoke is not a function
    at Context.<anonymous>'

Comment: Sorry, I went off memory and was incorrect.  I updated the answer with some code directly from a working test of mine (but put your selector in place).  I found this to be a bit finicky when I was figuring it out and some types of element did not work with this, so hopefully it works for you.

Comment: No luck yet, I have tried as below, but log is not logging the value entered in text field 'cy.get('input[name="email"]').invoke('text').then(text=>{
  const sometext = text;
  cy.log(sometext);
  
 })'

Comment: @ Brendan, Figured out at last, instead of invoke('text'), used invoke('val'). Now Cypress is logging the variable value... 'cy
 .get('input[name="email"]').invoke('val').then(val => {
  const sometext = val;
  cy.log(sometext); 
 })'

Comment: @soccerway good to hear, what did the element look like that that worked with?

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="email" required="required">

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to massage or work with the text prior to an assertion:

```js
cy.get('input').should(($input) => {
  const val = $input.val()
})
```

[using-cypress-faq](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq#How-do-I-get-an-input-s-value)

Answer (score -2):

[.contains('your-value')](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Syntax) worked for me

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)