# How to get value of a DatePicker Cypress

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

I am doing some E2E test using cypress and I want to get the date that appears on a DatePicker element from my react app.
I tried this but both return an empty string:

```
cy.get('input[name="Date"]').invoke('attr', 'value').then((text) => {
    expect('08/05/2019').to.equal(text);
});
```

```
cy.get('input[name="Date"]').invoke(text).then((text) => {
    expect('08/05/2019').to.equal(text);
});
```

I would like to get the value of this DatePicker which is always today by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to this post [How to get the text input field value to a const and log that value in Cypress.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793521/how-to-get-the-text-input-field-value-to-a-const-and-log-that-value-in-cypress-i)

I found the answer, it seems I should treat the datepiker input as a text input.

```
cy.get('input[name="Date"]').invoke('val').then((text) => {
    expect('08/05/2019').to.equal(text);
});
```