# Cypress - Checking value property inside a div

Tags: input, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, cypress-component-test-runner, cypress-custom-commands

I'm trying to check the value of the value field inside a div.
this value is not reflected to a string or a int in the div value, only in his attribute:

```html
<input as-automation="" type="text" placeholder="Put the initial value here" value="999.99">
```

please look a value of 999.99, how can I reach it? I tried valueof, contains, eq, nothing worked..

I want to find the way to reach this value by cypress.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the text input field value to a const and log that value in Cypress.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793521/how-to-get-the-text-input-field-value-to-a-const-and-log-that-value-in-cypress-i)

Comment: I'm confused. You say you want to get a value field inside a div, but I don't see any `div` elements in your example, just an `input` element.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reference the element's `value` by the key `value`, either through the Chai assertion (via `cy.should()`) or in `cy.its()`.

```js
cy.get('input').should('have.value', '999.99');
...
cy.get('input').its('value').then((value) => {
  // other code where you do something with the `value` variable
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to check it.

```js
const value = "999.99";
cy.get("input").should("have.value", value);

cy.get("input").should(($input) => {
  const val = $input.val();

  expect(val).to.eq(value);
});

cy.get("input").invoke("val").should("eq", value);
```

Here is a working [example](https://github.com/jjhelguero/cypress-examples/blob/main/cypress/e2e/checkElementValue.md).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is:

```js
cy.get('input').should('have.attr', 'value', '999.99')
```