# Asserting Vuetify v-text-field value using Cypress

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cypress, vuetify.js

I am writing an E2E test suite using Cypress for my Vue+Vuetify frontend. I want to assess the value of a read-only v-text-field as its value is a computed property based on previous user input.
So my v-text-field simply looks like:

```
<v-text-field
    data-cy="npa-display"
    :readonly="true"
    :model-value="this.npa"
    class="mt-4"
></v-text-field>
```

Then in my Cypress test I have this assertion:

```
cy.get("[data-cy='npa-display']").contains("Test-Team");
```

This assertions fails unexpectedly because it does not find the text in the selected DOM tree. However, when I manually search the entire DOM, the expected text is nowhere to be found, while the text is actually displayed on my screen.

1. How can it be that something that is shown on screen can not be found in the HTML DOM?
2. And, more importantly, how can I assert the v-text-field's value using Cypress?

Comment: input text is never displayed in the DOM, even for native input elements.  the value is stored on a _property_ of the element, namely the `value` property.  I don't have experience with cypress but maybe you'll find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793521) helpful. Do note that v-text-field is actually a wrapper element surrounding a native input element so you may need to do some traversal to get the actual inner value.

Comment: @yoduh that makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, `v-text-field` uses an `<input>` to hold the text as a `.value` property.

The Vuetify code you posted probably looks like this in the DOM at runtime

```html
<div class="v-text-field" data-cy="npa-display">
  <div class="v-input__control">
     ... // more vuetify feature divs here
     <input class="v-field__input">
```

In Cypress to assert the text use

```js
cy.get('data-cy="npa-display"]')      // data-cy will be on top-level div
  .find('input')                      // drill down to input
  .should('have.value', 'Test-Team')
```